# CentOS lost Root Access

Tags: centos, unix, sudo, root

For some reason I cannot access my root user via SSH. It displays the error on login:

```
could not open session.
```

However I happen to have another user account that is a normal non-sudo user. Is there any way I can run a `su root` command or anything to make this user with `sudo` privilege?

I have the password of the root user.

Comment: Did you try running `su`?

Comment: Yes I did. su root and it's the same message: could not open session". I was thinking maybe the sudo command has some kind of an option to specify the username and a password in order not to use the DEFAULT logged in username..

Comment: What changes did you make immediately prior to this happening ?

Comment: I added some changes in the limits.conf file set the soft and hard limit for user root to unlimited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you messed up your limits such that they prevent you from logging in, you'll need to reboot the machine into maintenance mode.  Depending on exactly what sort of problem you created, adding `single` to your boot options (in grub, hit "e" to edit the `kernel` line, add `single` to the end, hit esc to exit, then press "b" to boot) will often be enough to give you a shell.  If you messed things up in a slightly different way, try adding `init=/bin/bash` to the end, instead.  In either event, that should give you enough access to resolve the issue.

If none of that works or in the worst case, you can always fire up a LiveCD and mount the affected drive in order to undo the changes you made.

Comment: The problem is I don`t have a "phisical" access to the Host. It's ordered from a hosting company. I only have ssh access to it :(

Comment: Speaking as someone who works for a hosting company: if you ask Support to give you a hand with this, I 100% guarantee they have a process in place for adding these sorts of parameters to the boot process.  And if you ask very nicely and describe what you did very well, they'll likely be able to very quickly solve your limit issue.  There's even a small chance they can do it without rebooting the machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would submit a ticket and nicely ask them to fix my stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone (who knows the password...) can use `su` to switch to root (as opposed to `sudo`).

Comment: as stated before, it gives me an error: " could not open session" due to an increase of the ulimit I did.

Comment: so basically you screwed yourself over :P?

Comment: Pretty much..  Anything I could possibly do to revert the cahnges or anything? I have criticall datas on this host.

Comment: Restore your backups?

Comment: I have none.. well I might be able to save the datas somehow but it's a LAST ULTIMATE RESORT.  ..